# Angular main-client.js request fail with net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERR

Tags: angular, azure, iis, .net-core, azure-devops

I have angular 5 application which was hosted on Azure VM(IIS). Sometimes application not loading and in developer tools, I can see that the following error is printed.

**dist/main-client.js?v=cKNdK5mCcqFb_XcypJtFLs5ZJFfx4Fcyxd_Dfx6hHpY net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERR**

This issue has not occurred frequently for all users. I have monitored my http requests and found that request protocol is h2.

Are there any fixes I have to implement in my angular application to solve this issue? Or Are there any implementation in the server-side?